# Icon is not aligning with text inside a button

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

I have a button element with a span inside it for displaying an icon inside the button. But they are not aligned. I referred many forum posts and they suggest middle align – but that does not resolve the issue. Any other way to fix the issue?

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/Vw9Z6/432/

**HTM Code**

```
<button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default app-custom-button-request"><span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-star app-span"></span>Request</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.app-custom-button-request 
{
   color:red;
   margin-left:10px; 
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle; 
   width:200px;
}
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This fixes it:

```
.ui-icon {display: inline-block;}
```

The `.ui-icon` is set to `block` display.

**Preview**

[image: Imgur]

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5c5zc72d/**